# Qt : execute a slot each time a QTableWidget change its geometry?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, slot

I've made a widget derived from QTableWidget and I would like to execute a slot each time the a column or a line is resize, and each time the widget is resized. How to do that as there is no signal for that ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For resizing of the widget itself: Inherit from `QTableView`, add a signal reimplement [resizeEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent). In your `resizeEvent` `emmit` your new signal and call the base implementation of `resizeEvent` to actually do the resizing.

For resizing of columns: Use the [signals from the associated QHeaderView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#signals) which you can obtain with [horizontalHeader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#horizontalHeader)